# node.js -- cannot figure out why it's not awaiting the Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to web-dev and am writing a function to query my local ES node. I've spent a decent amount of time with REST API POST's with Python and believe I understand roughly how the async, etc. is supposed to work based off of that experience, but I cannot figure out why this particular function is not awaiting the query and always returning promise. Current implementation looks like this:

```
async function query (index_name, body_json){
    try{
        let sr = await(client.search({
            index: index_name,
            body: {"query": body_json,
                   "size": 15
            }
        }));
        return sr
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

My original implementation used `.then().catch()` as such:

```
    client.search({
        index: index_name,
        body: {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
                // this is where "body_json" param would go
            },
            "size": 15
        }
    })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

I also spent some, but much less, time playing around with something a la [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57739314/nodejs-elasticsearch-search-returns-promise-instead-of-values).

From what I've read online, these two are functionally "equivalent," and, from the confident tones of all of these SO posts and Medium blogs, this ostensibly should be trivially returning the JSON results, but it's not (yet to try something a la [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889010/javascript-function-to-return-elasticsearch-results), but noticed there's no async whatsoever here. Extra kudos if you know why that is).

Genuinely unsure of where I'm going wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you try removing the parentheses after `await`. I think that is being interpreted as a function call.

Comment: The `query` function returns a promise - not the result. So you have to use your `.then()` and `.catch()` on the return from `query`: `query(...).then(response=>console.log(response));`

Comment: and I didn't see the parens @AnuragKumar mentioned.

Comment: @AnuragKumar Should have mentioned that I have done that already... was not cathartic. Going to play with Randy's suggestions

Comment: How are you using `query`? `await` is never considered a reference inside `async` context. It would otherwise be a bug with the javascript engine.

Comment: @MinusFour it's just going to be used to query Elasticsearch node --> retrieve the hits off of it, so it "isn't" being used currently, if that makes sense.

Comment: I meant like in actual code. How are using `query` right now (as in code) that it doesn't get you the result you want.

Comment: Mocha tests @MinusFour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning something from an `async` function is the same as returning promise. So, your query function returns a promise with the result of the `client.search`. The following code will await for your query promise and print the result. You could also use the `sr` value inside your query function as here the promise has also resolved.

```
let result = await query(some_index_name, some_body_json)
console.log(result)
```

[Here](https://javascript.info/promise-basics) is a great tutorial about JavaScript promises and async/await.